# Make Azure Function run sequential on ServiceBusTrigger - maxConcurrentCalls not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function which looks like this

```
[FunctionName("Dispatcher")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger(queueName: "defaultqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsQueue")]string queueMessage, TraceWriter log)
{

    Dictionary<string, string> payload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(queueMessage);
    string url = payload["url"];

    try
    {
        log.Info("Collect result: " + url);

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result)
        {
            int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

            if (statusCode == 200)
            {
                var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                DoStuff(log, responseString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The GET on the HttpClient takes roughly one minute. I want to wait for this call to finish until the next message is retrieved from the Service Bus Queue.

My host.json looks like this

```
{
    "functionTimeout": "23:00:00",
    "serviceBus": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
        "prefetchCount": 1,
        "autoRenewTimeout": "00:05:00"
    }
}
```

However, when I put messages in the Service Bus Queue and run the Function, I instantly see multiple "Collect result: http://example.com" in the logs which apparently means, multiple instances of the Function are running in parallel. How can I configure Azure Functions to wait until HttpClient and DoStuff() is finished until pulling a new message from the Queue?

Comment: Seems that it is not possible unfortunately: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/912

Comment: You could try to use `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to limit  the scaling of function apps. For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2667).

Comment: This can be achieved, but it is a bit hidden: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#host-json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can still use the functionality that was ported from web jobs.  In order to only execute the function once across all instances put this attribute above your method.

```
  [Singleton(Mode = SingletonMode.Listener)]
```

This isnt documented in the Functions sdk but it looks like its still there.  Here is the webjobs documentation. [Azure Web Jobs SDK Singleton](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton)

Comment: You are right, this works (when using C# for your Azure Function)

Answer (score 2):

Anyone landing here using functions v2 - the `host.json` Service Bus binding configuration [is different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings) than in v1.

E.g.:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "prefetchCount": 100,
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": true,
                "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
            },
            "sessionHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": false,
                "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
                "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
            }
        }
    }
}
```