# MaxConcurrentCalls = 0 yet still have worker threads when working locally with azure service bus

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure

I have an azure service bus queue set up. Within the host.json file I have maxConcurrentCalls set to 1 however when i debug the app locally there are 8-10 worker threads running and its making the app impossible to debug. How do i have only 1 thread running when i debug my app locally?

Initially my host.json was empty and i found the below code that was supposed to have in order to have only 1 thread execution see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#host-json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
      "serviceBus": {
          "prefetchCount": 100,
          "messageHandlerOptions": {
          "autoComplete": false,
          "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
          "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00"
         }
       }
     }
 }
```

I added the host.json settings to my local.json settings to no avail, i still get 10 worker threads starting up on launch.
I also attempted to make the function call a singleton see 
[Make Azure Function run sequential on ServiceBusTrigger - maxConcurrentCalls not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900791/make-azure-function-run-sequential-on-servicebustrigger-maxconcurrentcalls-not)
however, this just locked up the function completely and didnt solve any issues at all.

```
   [FunctionName("ReadFromXCagoIssueQueueAndRetrieveFiles")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger(QueueName, AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "SBConnection")]BrokeredMessage myQueueItem, TextWriter log)
    {
        log.WriteLine($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        var propIssueId = myQueueItem.Properties["IssueId"].ToString();
        var issueId = int.Parse(propIssueId);
        log.WriteLine($"begin grab files for issue: {issueId}");
        retrieveIssueEPub(issueId);
    }
```

The execution of retrieveIssueEPub is performed over several worker threads which means that the message ends up in deadletter queue after 1 run of the function due to it splitting the same message across all the threads and not the 1 thread that i expect due to the max concurrent calls. am i missing something? Is there a difference between concurrently pulling out 1 message at a time and executing the function over several threads?

Comment: Service Bus applications are *supposed* to serve multiple messages concurrently. The same holds for any web application for that matter. That doesn't make them harder to debug. Multiple workers *won't* receive the same message unless the receiving code is buggy. The code you posted here is buggy - it doesn't call [BrokeredMessage.Complete()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.complete?view=azure-dotnet) so the message appears in the queue again once its lease expires. Just call `Complete()`

Comment: I don't know what your code is supposed to do. What I do know is that when you get a message you have to explicitly say it's received by calling `Complete()` otherwise it's assumed your worker failed and the message will reappear in the queue. That's no different than using database transactions and forgetting to call `COMMIT`. That's how all queueing systems work, except that distributed queues like those used by AWS, Google Azure don't lock a message, they *hide* it for a specified time.

Comment: I have changed the host.json to have autocomplete, however this doesnt change the issue of the lock being reached and not being refreshed. So if the messages autocomplete i still get multiple threads occuring?

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine has found the error.
the application is only firing one thread at a time. However on azure itself the lock duration was set to 30 seconds.
This means that the app would start new a new thread after 30 seconds etc because the message becomes unlocked.
Extending the lock has solved the issue.

Comment: This *covered up* the issue by hobbling production. The issue remains, messages aren't processed in time, or the code forgets to call `Complete()` on the message to  remove it from the queue. Now though, you have a bigger issue, messages that will take too long to be retried in case of problems